# Socketio no funciona en producción

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io

Hola tengo un problema de que no me funciona socketio en producción. Estoy utilizando dos puertos (uno para el socket:4001 y el otro para las rutas:4000). La pregunta es, que url debo poner en lugar de localhost:4001 en el client initialize cuando está en producción. Cabe destacar que tengo el backend y el cliente por separado

Comment: Lo suyo es usar un servidor en modo [*proxy reverso (o inverso)*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servidor_proxy#Proxy_inverso), que es el que se comunicará internamente con tu aplicación NodeJS. Exponer una aplicación o servidor NodeJS directamente a Internet es una muy mala idea, por muchos motivos, siendo la seguridad el principal de ellos. Saludos

Comment: Cómo impplementaria el proxy? con PM2?. Podrías enviarme un ejemplo de configuración. Gracias

Comment: @MauricioContreras

Comment: Un servidor web que implementa proxy inverso es Apache. Otra opción es usar nginx e incluso Microsoft IIS. La idea es que dicho servidor reciba la petición, y sea mediante el Proxy que la misma sea redirigida a tu aplicación NodeJS. La respuesta de tu aplicación luego será enviada al cliente desde el Servidor Web. Todo esto es transparente al cliente y tu aplicación Node no estaría expuesta directamente a Internet. Saludos